# How do I change quaternion rotation to use the local camera axis rather than the world axis in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, camera, rotation, directx, quaternions

I'm currently trying to rotate the camera around its local axis based on keyboard/mouse input and the code I currently have uses DirectXMath and works nicely, however it is using the world axis to rotate around rather than the cameras local axis. Because of this, some of the rotations are not as expected and causes issues as the camera rotates. For example, when we tilt our camera, the Y axis will change and we will want to rotate around another axis to get our expected results.

What am I doing wrong in the code or what do I need to change in order to rotate around its local axis?

vector.x, vector.y, vector.z (The vector to rotate around, i.e. (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))

```
//define our camera matrix
XMFLOAT4X4 cameraMatrix;

//position, lookat, up values for the camera
XMFLOAT3 position;
XMFLOAT3 up;
XMFLOAT3 lookat;

void Camera::rotate(XMFLOAT3 vector, float theta) {
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix, XMMatrixIdentity());

//set our view quaternion to our current camera's lookat position
XMVECTOR viewQuaternion = XMQuaternionIdentity();
viewQuaternion = XMVectorSet(lookat.x, lookat.y, lookat.z, 0.0f);

//set the rotation vector based on our parameter, i.e (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
//to rotate around the x axis
XMVECTOR rotationVector = XMVectorSet(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z, 0.0f);
//create a rotation quaternion to rotate around our vector, with a specified angle, theta
XMVECTOR rotationQuaternion = XMVectorSet(
XMVectorGetX(rotationVector) * sin(theta / 2),
XMVectorGetY(rotationVector) * sin(theta / 2),
XMVectorGetZ(rotationVector) * sin(theta / 2),
cos(theta / 2));

//get our rotation quaternion inverse
XMVECTOR rotationInverse = XMQuaternionInverse(rotationQuaternion);

//new view quaternion = [ newView = ROTATION * VIEW * INVERSE ROTATION ]
//multiply our rotation quaternion with our view quaternion
XMVECTOR newViewQuaternion = XMQuaternionMultiply(rotationQuaternion, viewQuaternion);

//multiply the result of our calculation above with the inverse rotation
//to get our new view values
newViewQuaternion = XMQuaternionMultiply(newViewQuaternion, rotationInverse);

//take the new lookat values from our newViewQuaternion and put them into the camera
lookat = XMFLOAT3(XMVectorGetX(newViewQuaternion), XMVectorGetY(newViewQuaternion), XMVectorGetZ(newViewQuaternion));

//build our camera matrix using XMMatrixLookAtLH
XMStoreFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix, XMMatrixLookAtLH(
    XMVectorSet(position.x, position.y, position.z, 0.0f),
    XMVectorSet(lookat.x, lookat.y, lookat.z, 0.0f),
    XMVectorSet(up.x, up.y, up.z, 0.0f)));
}
```

The view matrix is then set

```
//store our camera's matrix inside the view matrix
XMStoreFloat4x4(&_view, camera->getCameraMatrix() );
```

-

Edit:

I have tried an alternative solution without using quaternions, and it seems I can get the camera to rotate correctly around its own axis, however the camera's lookat values now never change and after I have stopped using the mouse/keyboard, it snaps back to its original position.

```
void Camera::update(float delta) {
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix, XMMatrixIdentity());

//do we have a rotation?
//this is set as we try to rotate, around a current axis such as
//(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
if (rotationVector.x != 0.0f || rotationVector.y != 0.0f || rotationVector.z != 0.0f) {

    //yes, we have an axis to rotate around

//create our axis vector to rotate around
    XMVECTOR axisVector = XMVectorSet(rotationVector.x, rotationVector.y, rotationVector.z, 0.0f);

//create our rotation matrix using XMMatrixRotationAxis, and rotate around this axis with a specified angle theta
    XMMATRIX rotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationAxis(axisVector, 2.0 * delta);

//create our camera's view matrix
    XMMATRIX viewMatrix = XMMatrixLookAtLH(
        XMVectorSet(position.x, position.y, position.z, 0.0f),
        XMVectorSet(lookat.x, lookat.y, lookat.z, 0.0f),
        XMVectorSet(up.x, up.y, up.z, 0.0f));

//multiply our camera's view matrix by the rotation matrix
//make sure the rotation is on the right to ensure local axis rotation
    XMMATRIX finalCameraMatrix = viewMatrix * rotationMatrix;


/* this piece of code allows the camera to correctly rotate and it doesn't
snap back to its original position, as the lookat coordinates are being set
each time. However, this will make the camera rotate around the world axis
rather than the local axis. Which brings us to the same problem we had
with the quaternion rotation */
    //XMVECTOR look = XMVectorSet(lookat.x, lookat.y, lookat.z, 0.0);

    //XMVECTOR finalLook = XMVector3Transform(look, rotationMatrix);

    //lookat.x = XMVectorGetX(finalLook);
    //lookat.y = XMVectorGetY(finalLook);
    //lookat.z = XMVectorGetZ(finalLook);

//finally store the finalCameraMatrix into our camera matrix
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix, finalCameraMatrix);
} else {

    //no, there is no rotation, don't apply the roation matrix

//no rotation, don't apply the rotation matrix
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix, XMMatrixLookAtLH(
        XMVectorSet(position.x, position.y, position.z, 0.0f),
        XMVectorSet(lookat.x, lookat.y, lookat.z, 0.0f),
        XMVectorSet(up.x, up.y, up.z, 0.0f)));
}
```

An example can be seen here: https://i.gyazo.com/f83204389551eff427446e06624b2cf9.mp4

I think I am missing setting the actual lookat value to the new lookat value, but I'm not sure how to calculate the new value, or extract it from the new view matrix (which I have already tried)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have already tried to re-order the calculations with no success. My understanding is that the calculation I need to use is "newView = rotation * view * inverseRotation". I have managed to get local rotation without using quaternions, but the camera values did not update to world space.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing in your code. There are so many things going on and the lack of comments and explanations of variables don't help to understand what you actually want to do. If you just want to rotate the current camera, multiply the view matrix (or quaternion) by a rotation matrix (or quaternion). The order depends on the matrix layout.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have added comments to the code, but that is essentially what it does. It multiplies the current view by a rotation quaternion. I have tried changing the order of this many times. I'm sure it could be a multiplication issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: I see what you are trying. The problem is that you are rotating only a single point (the lookat vector). And the point is not aware of any camera orientation. As I said, multiply the entire `cameraMatrix` by a rotation (and I don't see why you would use quaternions here).

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have tried an alternative without using quaternions and updated my OP with the new code. This does rotate correctly as I want it to, however the lookat coordinates never actually change even though the camera is correctly rotating, so when I stop moving the mouse, or release keys on the keyboard the camera will snap back to its original lookat values. Am I missing something?

Comment: Rotation in local or global frame depends on left or right hand transformation multiplication

Twhole = Tprev * R -> rotation in local frame 
Twhole = R *Tprev -> rotation in world frame